# Reputation limit for adding a comment

Tags: discussion

This is the problem:

I want to answer some questions but the question is not very clear. So I need to ask for more information by adding a comment. Unfortunately, I need 50 reputation for adding a comment. 
That means I need to answer questions and get upvotes in order to get the 50 reputation.

Then the problem reappears, I am not able to add a comment, so not esay to answer well questions.

Is there a quick solution for getting enough reputation for adding a comment? Otherwise I can only wait for one day that I see a question answerable for me and expect the answer to be upvoted.

Comment: Answer those questions that are clear. The rules about comments was in effect when I started being active on SO. Did not stop me.

Comment: Easy questions are low-hanging fruit. Even if you're not the only right answer, people are willing to give upvotes if you provide a decent answer.

Comment: If you can't answer without leaving a comment, move on.

Comment: While I understand the frustration, Lelouchzqy, you can just answer 1-2 questions that don't need clarification, and then you will hav the rep. Getting 50 is pretty easy :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make 25 **high-quality** suggested edits.  [This post explains how](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work).

Each edit that is accepted by the community is worth 2 reputation points.